# How to serialize a generic class to XML?

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

Objects of the following class can be serialized to XML as intended, as long as the actual type of the generic field `Object` is contained in the list of `XmlElement` attributes:

```
public class SerializedObject<T> : Serializable where T : Serializable
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Type = typeof(Weapon))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Type = typeof(Armor))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Type = typeof(QuestItem))]
    public T Object;

    public string ObjectId;
    public int ID;

    public SerializedObject() { }

    public SerializedObject(T _object)
    {
        Object = _object;
        ID = Object.Id;
        ObjectId = Object.ObjectId;
    }
}
```

The question is:

How can I serialize an object of this class, including the generic field `Object` without specifiying all possible types for `T` in `XmlElement` attributes?

Comment: FYI, C# doesn't have templates. It has generics, which are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this too. What I did is create a wrapper class:

```
public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument<XmlEntity>(XmlEntity o)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc;
    SerializeWrapper<XmlEntity> wrapper = new SerializeWrapper<XmlEntity>();
    wrapper.XmlObject = o;

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(wrapper.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xs.Serialize(ms, wrapper);
        xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        ms.Position = 0;
        xdoc.Load(ms);
    }

    return xdoc;
}
```

Here is the class used to wrap the object

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class SerializeWrapper<TObject>
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TObject XmlObject { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can just call it as:

```
Weapon weapon = new Weapon()
var xdoc = SerializeToXmlDocument<Weapon>(weapon);
```